# Issue connecting to gearhost database

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server

I'm trying to connect with C# code to a SQL Server database hosted on gear host using the `System.Data.SqlClient` library, but it doesn't work, I get an error "Server does not exist or connection refused."

Maybe I need do install some driver? Or is there anything wrong with my code?

```
string connetionString = "Data Source=mssql.gear.host:1433;Initial Catalog=databasename;User ID=userid;Password=mypassword";
SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);

try
{
    cnn.Open();
    Console.WriteLine("Connection Open!");
    cnn.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    Console.WriteLine(ex);
}
```

Comment: Do you want to tell us what the the problem is? Do you get an error or something...

Comment: yes i get an error Server does not exist or connection refused.

Comment: can you connect to it using another tool like sql server mgmt studio (if possible). Just try another way of connecting to see if you can connect to it without using your code.

Comment: yes i connected with dbeaver(a free Database management tool) from my mac

Comment: Can anybody help me with that?

Answer (score 0):

when removing the port it works ,obviously the database in gear host doesn't use a port